# Best database and hardware to choose for this use case

Tags: mysql, mongodb, bigdata, database, nosql

I will have a one table database of users with uuids, age, gender, family income and 12 such fields. About 40 - 50 million of them. I would need to query based on age range, income range etc. and get the list of uuid's out. Each row should be around 400 characters if concatenated. Multiplying 400 bytes by 50Mil gets arond 17 - 18 GB Approx. It will grow but slowly.

Which will be the best database system to hold this data and execute fast queries. Mongo or MySQL ? Also what kind of hardware should be best to keep.

Also, can someone tell query time mySQL or Mongo will take based on experience. I need to design architecture of some other components of the entire system based on this.

Comment: I would say Mongo, seems pointless using a relational database for one table

Comment: I hate to use this line (cliche alert) but: "I have indexes bigger than that". Plus this if off topic, [Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/179419).

Answer (score 2):

I would not say that 40-50 million records or 17-18GB would be considered "large".  Any relational database should be sufficient.

Any modern server will be sufficient.  Windows, Linux - choose the one you know best.  I'd say 64 bits are required.  Add [enough RAM](https://serverfault.com/questions/31394/where-to-purchase-a-server-capable-of-512gb-of-ram) and you'll be able to hold the whole thing in memory.

No one can tell you query time, because it depends on too many factors: hardware, schema, indexes, etc.  Best thing to do is time it yourself and see.

I think your biggest problem will be querying by ranges.  This sounds less like a transactional database and more like a data mining warehouse.  Perhaps a star schema with dimensions for time, location, income, etc. would be a better fit for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you should be storing all of that information in a single table, especially one with that many rows. For a project this large, I highly recommend learning how Relational Databases work and how indexing works. The way you're about to implement this, is going to be slow on any database or hardware you throw at it. Where as if you designed it as a relational database, with several separate tables to store things and use a foreign key to access those other tables, then you're going to increase your performance considerably.

[This is very dry](http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx), but essential. You should really try to get a good understanding of it.

Furthermore, you should read about [indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index). Each database does their slightly different, so how you implement it is dependent on the database you choose.

And I do mean you will increase your performance considerably. I have seen and redesigned poorly done queries that have taken 15-20minutes, optimized them through relational database design, indexes, and optimal query design and reduced them down to milliseconds.

Comment: The way data is transferred into it from different sources makes it difficult to store in multiple related tables.